# Strange table error in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Okay, so I've got a strange problem with the following Lua code:

```
function quantizeNumber(i, step)
    local d = i / step
    d = round(d, 0)
    return d*step
end

bar = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

local objects = {}
local foo = #bar * 3
for i=1, #foo do
    objects[i] = bar[quantizeNumber(i, 3)]
end
print(#fontObjects)
```

After this code has been run, the length of objects *should* be 15, right? But no, it's 4. How is this working and what am I missing?

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville.

Comment: I'm sure this is extracted from a larger project, but there are a bunch of errors in this.  e.g. `#foo` doesn't work since `foo` isn't a table.  And `fontObjects` isn't defined (I'm guessing you meant `#objects`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is 4.

From the Lua reference manual:

> The length of a table t is defined to be any integer index n such that t[n] is not nil and t[n+1] is nil; moreover, if t[1] is nil, n can be zero. For a regular array, with non-nil values from 1 to a given n, its length is exactly that n, the index of its last value. If the array has "holes" (that is, nil values between other non-nil values), then #t can be any of the indices that directly precedes a nil value (that is, it may consider any such nil value as the end of the array).

Let's modify the code to see what is in the table:

```
local objects = {}
local foo = #bar * 3
for i=1, foo do
    objects[i] = bar[quantizeNumber(i, 3)]
    print("At " .. i .. " the value is " .. (objects[i] and objects[i] or "nil"))
end
print(objects)
print(#objects)
```

When you run this you see that `objects[4]` is 3 but `objects[5]` is `nil`.  Here is the output:

```
$ lua quantize.lua 
At 1 the value is nil
At 2 the value is 3
At 3 the value is 3
At 4 the value is 3
At 5 the value is nil
At 6 the value is nil
At 7 the value is nil
At 8 the value is nil
At 9 the value is nil
At 10 the value is nil
At 11 the value is nil
At 12 the value is nil
At 13 the value is nil
At 14 the value is nil
At 15 the value is nil
table: 0x1001065f0
4
```

It is true that you filled in 15 slots of the table.  However the `#` operator on tables, as defined by the reference manual, does not care about this.  It simply looks for an index where the value is not nil, and whose following index **is** nil.

In this case, the index that satisfies this condition is 4.

That is why the answer is 4.  It's just the way Lua is.

The nil can be seen as representing the end of an array.  It's kind of like in C how a zero byte in the middle of a character array is actually *the end of a string* and the "string" is only those characters before it.

If your intent was to produce the table `1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5` then you will need to rewrite your `quantize` function as follows:

```
function quantizeNumber(i, step)
    return math.ceil(i / step)
end
```

Comment: But `bar` is five elements long. I should be doing a for loop from 1 to 15, 15 being the length of bar * 3, as I specified earlier. Shouldn't that leave me with 15 items? Why am I getting 4 items?

Comment: @Elliot, I've answered this question in an edit to my answer. HTH.

Comment: Okay, so I'm filling my array up to item 4. Why isn't it going past index 4? I'd expect that the output would like something like this: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ... 5, 5, 5. Why isn't it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In this case the quantizeNumber function was wrong.  See the latest addendum to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function `quantizeNumber` is wrong. The function you're looking for is math.fmod:

```
objects[i] = bar[math.fmod(i, 3)]
```